# How can I get percentage of each answer in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I have a poll system. I use this query to get count of every answer of question. How can I get percentage of every answered option like this:

```
question 1 ---> option1=20.13 % ---> option2=79.87 %

question 2 ---> option3=100 %

question 3 ---> option4=30 % ---> option5=70 %

....
```

I tried this query But is not my desire:

```
[getPollResult]

@poll_form_id int

AS
BEGIN

SELECT a.question_id,a.title,COUNT(*) vote 
FROM tbl_poll_option a 
  JOIN tbl_poll_answer b ON a.Id=b.option_id
  JOIN tbl_poll_question c ON a.question_id=c.Id
WHERE poll_form_id=@poll_form_id 
GROUP BY a.title,a.question_id

END
```

Comment: @ChanomFirst Microsoft SQL SERVER

Comment: sample input data and Sample Output Data as per your requirement this kind of options and arrows can be handled in Front End application as far as to get proper answer post Question clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the advice of doing calculations (like percentages) on the front end.

Having said that, this might be helpful for you.

Design limitations: this is suitable for relatively small data sets, and I find the "with()" syntax easier to work with than making temp tables and hoping I remember to clean them up.  (for more on the "with...as.." sytnax [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)  ).

The following sql (untested) attempts to generate two temporary result sets.

```
counts_by_option - # of votes for each question+option pair
counts_by_question - total # of votes for each question
```

Let's ease into it:

### counts_by_option

This is more or less what you started with (just a little more actually, I think we'll likely want to know both question & option later, so we grab both of them now):

```
with counts_by_option( question_id, question_title, option_id, option_title, vote_cnt )
as (
   SELECT opt.question_id
        , quest.title as question_title
        , opt.id as option_id
        , opt.title as option_title
        , COUNT(*) vote_cnt
   FROM tbl_poll_option opt
   JOIN tbl_poll_answer ans     ON ans.option_id = opt.Id
   JOIN tbl_poll_question quest ON quest.Id = opt.question_id
   WHERE poll_form_id=@poll_form_id
   GROUP BY opt.question_id, quest.title, opt.id, opt.title
)
select * from counts_by_option
order by question_id, option_id
```

If that works, let's extend the sql and add our next temporary result set...

### counts_by_question

Now we can use our option-totals to generate the grand total of votes for each question; we'll need that in a bit to compute the actual %ge.

```
with counts_by_option( question_id, question_title, option_id, option_title, vote_cnt )
as (
   SELECT opt.question_id
        , quest.title as question_title
        , opt.id as option_id
        , opt.title as option_title
        , COUNT(*) vote_cnt
   FROM tbl_poll_option opt
   JOIN tbl_poll_answer ans     ON ans.option_id = opt.Id
   JOIN tbl_poll_question quest ON quest.Id = opt.question_id
   WHERE poll_form_id=@poll_form_id
   GROUP BY opt.question_id, quest.title, opt.id, opt.title
)
-- select * from counts_by_option order by question_id, option_id
-- (I like to comment out select but leave in place for future testing...)
, counts_by_question( question_id, question_total_votes )
as (
   select question_id, sum(vote_cnt) as question_total_votes 
   from counts_by_option group by question_id
)
select * from counts_by_question order by question_id
```

If that worked we are (finally) in a position to answer the original question about percentages:

### percentages example

```
with counts_by_option( question_id, question_title, option_id, option_title, vote_cnt )
as (
   SELECT opt.question_id
        , quest.title as question_title
        , opt.id as option_id
        , opt.title as option_title
        , COUNT(*) vote_cnt
   FROM tbl_poll_option opt
   JOIN tbl_poll_answer ans     ON ans.option_id = opt.Id
   JOIN tbl_poll_question quest ON quest.Id = opt.question_id
   WHERE poll_form_id=@poll_form_id
   GROUP BY opt.question_id, quest.title, opt.id, opt.title
)
-- select * from counts_by_option order by question_id, option_id
-- (I like to comment out select but leave in place for future testing...)
, counts_by_question( question_id, question_total_votes )
as (
   select question_id, sum(vote_cnt) as question_total_votes 
   from counts_by_option group by question_id
)
-- select * from counts_by_question order by question_id
select question_id
     , question_title
     , option_id
     , option_title
     , vote_cnt
     , (100.0 * vote_cnt)
       / (select b.question_total_votes
          from counts_by_question b
          where b.question_id = a.question_id
         ) as option_percentage
from counts_by_option a
order by question_id, vote_cnt desc
```

The result set is driven by **counts_by_option  a**.

The percentages expression asks **counts_by_question  b** for help.

Let's focus on the expression for **option_percentage**:

```
(100.0 * vote_cnt)
/ (select b.question_total_votes
   from counts_by_question b
   where b.question_id = a.question_id
)
as option_percentage
```

This is kind of complex (which is why I prefer to do things like aggregations in the front end) but not too bad...

We start by multiplying **vote_count** by **100.0**.

Then we use the current OPTION to drive a sub-query that hits question_total_values to find our current question's total number of votes.

Note the qualifiers **a** and **b** which are important to focus our subquery against **counts_by_question** on only **a**'s current question using this where clause:  **where b.question_id = a.question_id**  (important since a subquery like that can only return a single value, otherwise it errors out at execution time).

This would blow up if any questions could have zero total votes (e.g. division by zero error).

edit: The way **counts_by_option** is constructed, only questions with answers (table **tbl_poll_answer**) would be used, so all of the values in **counts_by_question** will be non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

The schema for the above case

```
    CREATE TABLE #POLL_QUESTION (QUESTION_ID INT, QUESTION VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO #POLL_QUESTION 
    SELECT 1,'WHAT?'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'WHEN?'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'WHY?'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'WHERE?'


    CREATE TABLE #POLL_OPTION(OPTION_ID INT , QUESTION_ID INT, OPTION_NME VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO #POLL_OPTION
    SELECT 1,1,'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,1,'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,1,'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,2,'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,2,'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,2,'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,3,'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,3,'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9,3,'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10,4,'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11,4,'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 12,4,'C'

    CREATE TABLE #POLL_ANSWER(ANSWER_ID INT, OPTION_ID INT)
    INSERT INTO #POLL_ANSWER
    SELECT 1,2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9,8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10,9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11,10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 12,10
```

The Statment for the data

```
    SELECT Q.QUESTION_ID,Q.QUESTION,O.OPTION_NME,COUNT(O.OPTION_NME)COUNT_OPTION,LEFTQUERY.COUNT_QUESTION, (COUNT(O.OPTION_NME)*100)/LEFTQUERY.COUNT_QUESTION AS PER  FROM #POLL_QUESTION Q
    INNER JOIN #POLL_OPTION O ON Q.QUESTION_ID=O.QUESTION_ID
    INNER JOIN #POLL_ANSWER A ON O.OPTION_ID= A.OPTION_ID
    LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT Q.QUESTION_ID,Q.QUESTION, COUNt(O.OPTION_NME)COUNT_QUESTION FROM #POLL_QUESTION Q
    INNER JOIN #POLL_OPTION O ON Q.QUESTION_ID=O.QUESTION_ID
    INNER JOIN #POLL_ANSWER A ON O.OPTION_ID= A.OPTION_ID
    GROUP BY Q.QUESTION_ID,Q.QUESTION

    )AS LEFTQUERY ON  Q.QUESTION_ID= LEFTQUERY.QUESTION_ID
    GROUP BY Q.QUESTION_ID,Q.QUESTION,O.OPTION_NME,
    LEFTQUERY.COUNT_QUESTION
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  q.title,
  o.title,
  CAST(count(distinct o.id) as float) 
    / (SELECT count(allo.id)
       FROM option allo 
       WHERE q.option_FK = allo.id) 
    * 100.0,
FROM question q
  inner join option o on q.option_FK = o.id
GROUP BY q.id, q.title, q.option_FK, o.id, o.title
```

(probably needs some cleanup around the cast).

Would return this list:

```
question 1, option1, 20.13
question 1, option2, 79.87
question 2, option3, 100
question 3, option4, 30
question 3, option5, 70
```

It could be further processed ideally in a higher programming language.